# ImageView failing to Resize at runtime

Tags: java, android

I was looking [Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) and image crooper open source App by Edmodo, it does a pretty good job except instead of Image cropping I want to use it to scale my images, my Logic Was everytime the cropper Window/View changes in size I would change the height and width of my imageview to match the Crop view but everytime I do this, nothing happens, but looking at LogCat it seems my height and width do change except the imageview still looks the same even after changes below is the Class, my changes are commented in the `onSizeChanged()`

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013, Edmodo, Inc. 
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this work except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License in the LICENSE file, or at:
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" 
 * BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language 
 * governing permissions and limitations under the License. 
 */

package com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.edge.Edge;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.cropwindow.handle.Handle;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.util.AspectRatioUtil;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.util.HandleUtil;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.util.PaintUtil;

/**
* A custom View representing the crop window and the shaded background outside the crop window.
*/
 public class CropOverlayView extends View {

//region: Fields and Consts

private static final int SNAP_RADIUS_DP = 6;

private static final float DEFAULT_SHOW_GUIDELINES_LIMIT = 100;

// Gets default values from PaintUtil, sets a bunch of values such that the
// corners will draw correctly
private static final float DEFAULT_CORNER_THICKNESS_DP = PaintUtil.getCornerThickness();

private static final float DEFAULT_LINE_THICKNESS_DP = PaintUtil.getLineThickness();

private static final float DEFAULT_CORNER_OFFSET_DP = (DEFAULT_CORNER_THICKNESS_DP / 2) - (DEFAULT_LINE_THICKNESS_DP / 2);

private static final float DEFAULT_CORNER_EXTENSION_DP = DEFAULT_CORNER_THICKNESS_DP / 2
        + DEFAULT_CORNER_OFFSET_DP;

private static final float DEFAULT_CORNER_LENGTH_DP = 20;

private static final int GUIDELINES_ON_TOUCH = 1;

private static final int GUIDELINES_ON = 2;

private static RectF mRectF = new RectF();

/**
 * The Paint used to draw the white rectangle around the crop area.
 */
private Paint mBorderPaint;

/**
 * The Paint used to draw the guidelines within the crop area when pressed.
 */
private Paint mGuidelinePaint;

/**
 * The Paint used to draw the corners of the Border
 */
private Paint mCornerPaint;

/**
 * The Paint used to darken the surrounding areas outside the crop area.
 */
private Paint mBackgroundPaint;

/**
 * The bounding box around the Bitmap that we are cropping.
 */
private Rect mBitmapRect;

// The radius of the touch zone (in pixels) around a given Handle.
private float mHandleRadius;

// An edge of the crop window will snap to the corresponding edge of a
// specified bounding box when the crop window edge is less than or equal to
// this distance (in pixels) away from the bounding box edge.
private float mSnapRadius;

// Holds the x and y offset between the exact touch location and the exact
// handle location that is activated. There may be an offset because we
// allow for some leeway (specified by mHandleRadius) in activating a
// handle. However, we want to maintain these offset values while the handle
// is being dragged so that the handle doesn't jump.
private Pair<Float, Float> mTouchOffset;

// The Handle that is currently pressed; null if no Handle is pressed.
private Handle mPressedHandle;

// Flag indicating if the crop area should always be a certain aspect ratio
// (indicated by mTargetAspectRatio).
private boolean mFixAspectRatio = CropImageView.DEFAULT_FIXED_ASPECT_RATIO;

// Floats to save the current aspect ratio of the image
private int mAspectRatioX = CropImageView.DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_X;

private int mAspectRatioY = CropImageView.DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO_Y;

// The aspect ratio that the crop area should maintain; this variable is
// only used when mMaintainAspectRatio is true.
private float mTargetAspectRatio = ((float) mAspectRatioX) / mAspectRatioY;

/**
 * Instance variables for customizable attributes
 */
private int mGuidelines;

/**
 * The shape of the cropping area - rectangle/circular.
 */
private CropImageView.CropShape mCropShape;



// Whether the Crop View has been initialized for the first time
private boolean initializedCropWindow = false;

// Instance variables for the corner values
private float mCornerExtension;

private float mCornerOffset;

private float mCornerLength;
//endregion

public CropOverlayView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CropOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

/**
 * Informs the CropOverlayView of the image's position relative to the
 * ImageView. This is necessary to call in order to draw the crop window.
 *
 * @param bitmapRect the image's bounding box
 */
public void setBitmapRect(Rect bitmapRect) {
    mBitmapRect = bitmapRect;
    initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);
}

/**
 * Resets the crop overlay view.
 */
public void resetCropOverlayView() {

    if (initializedCropWindow) {
        initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);
        invalidate();
    }
}

/**
 * The shape of the cropping area - rectangle/circular.
 */
public void setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape cropShape) {
    mCropShape = cropShape;
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Sets the guidelines for the CropOverlayView to be either on, off, or to
 * show when resizing the application.
 *
 * @param guidelines Integer that signals whether the guidelines should be
 * on, off, or only showing when resizing.
 */
public void setGuidelines(int guidelines) {
    if (guidelines < 0 || guidelines > 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Guideline value must be set between 0 and 2. See documentation.");
    else {
        mGuidelines = guidelines;

        if (initializedCropWindow) {
            initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets whether the aspect ratio is fixed or not; true fixes the aspect
 * ratio, while false allows it to be changed.
 *
 * @param fixAspectRatio Boolean that signals whether the aspect ratio
 * should be maintained.
 */
public void setFixedAspectRatio(boolean fixAspectRatio) {
    mFixAspectRatio = fixAspectRatio;

    if (initializedCropWindow) {
        initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);
        invalidate();
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the X value of the aspect ratio; is defaulted to 1.
 *
 * @param aspectRatioX int that specifies the new X value of the aspect
 * ratio
 */
public void setAspectRatioX(int aspectRatioX) {
    if (aspectRatioX <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set aspect ratio value to a number less than or equal to 0.");
    else {
        mAspectRatioX = aspectRatioX;
        mTargetAspectRatio = ((float) mAspectRatioX) / mAspectRatioY;

        if (initializedCropWindow) {
            initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the Y value of the aspect ratio; is defaulted to 1.
 *
 * @param aspectRatioY int that specifies the new Y value of the aspect
 * ratio
 */
public void setAspectRatioY(int aspectRatioY) {
    if (aspectRatioY <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set aspect ratio value to a number less than or equal to 0.");
    else {
        mAspectRatioY = aspectRatioY;
        mTargetAspectRatio = ((float) mAspectRatioX) / mAspectRatioY;

        if (initializedCropWindow) {
            initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sets all initial values, but does not call initCropWindow to reset the
 * views. Used once at the very start to initialize the attributes.
 *
 * @param guidelines Integer that signals whether the guidelines should be
 * on, off, or only showing when resizing.
 * @param fixAspectRatio Boolean that signals whether the aspect ratio
 * should be maintained.
 * @param aspectRatioX float that specifies the new X value of the aspect
 * ratio
 * @param aspectRatioY float that specifies the new Y value of the aspect
 * ratio
 */
public void setInitialAttributeValues(int guidelines, boolean fixAspectRatio, int aspectRatioX, int aspectRatioY) {
    if (guidelines < 0 || guidelines > 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Guideline value must be set between 0 and 2. See documentation.");
    else
        mGuidelines = guidelines;

    mFixAspectRatio = fixAspectRatio;

    if (aspectRatioX <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set aspect ratio value to a number less than or equal to 0.");
    else {
        mAspectRatioX = aspectRatioX;
        mTargetAspectRatio = ((float) mAspectRatioX) / mAspectRatioY;
    }

    if (aspectRatioY <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set aspect ratio value to a number less than or equal to 0.");
    else {
        mAspectRatioY = aspectRatioY;
        mTargetAspectRatio = ((float) mAspectRatioX) / mAspectRatioY;
    }

}

//region: Private methods
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    // Initialize the crop window here because we need the size of the view
    // to have been determined.

    //my changes to update imageview height and width
    CropImageView.mImageView.getLayoutParams().height = h;
    CropImageView.mImageView.getLayoutParams().width = w;
    CropImageView.mImageView.requestLayout();
    CropImageView.mImageView.invalidate();


    initCropWindow(mBitmapRect);

   // CropImageView.mImageView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Draw translucent background for the cropped area.
    drawBackground(canvas, mBitmapRect);


    if (showGuidelines()) {
        // Determines whether guidelines should be drawn or not
        if (mGuidelines == GUIDELINES_ON) {
            drawRuleOfThirdsGuidelines(canvas);
        } else if (mGuidelines == GUIDELINES_ON_TOUCH) {
            // Draw only when resizing
            if (mPressedHandle != null)
                drawRuleOfThirdsGuidelines(canvas);
        }
    }

    float w = mBorderPaint.getStrokeWidth();
    float l = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate() + w;
    float t = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate() + w;
    float r = Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate() - w;
    float b = Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate() - w;
    if (mCropShape == CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE) {
        // Draw rectangle crop window border.
        canvas.drawRect(l, t, r, b, mBorderPaint);
        drawCorners(canvas);
    } else {
        // Draw circular crop window border
        mRectF.set(l, t, r, b);
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mBorderPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems") MotionEvent event) {

    // If this View is not enabled, don't allow for touch interactions.
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            onActionDown(event.getX(), event.getY());
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            onActionUp();
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            onActionMove(event.getX(), event.getY());
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
    }
}

private void init(Context context) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    mHandleRadius = HandleUtil.getTargetRadius(context);

    mSnapRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            SNAP_RADIUS_DP,
            displayMetrics);

    mBorderPaint = PaintUtil.newBorderPaint(context);
    mGuidelinePaint = PaintUtil.newGuidelinePaint();
    mBackgroundPaint = PaintUtil.newBackgroundPaint(context);
    mCornerPaint = PaintUtil.newCornerPaint(context);

    // Sets the values for the corner sizes
    mCornerOffset = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            DEFAULT_CORNER_OFFSET_DP,
            displayMetrics);
    mCornerExtension = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            DEFAULT_CORNER_EXTENSION_DP,
            displayMetrics);
    mCornerLength = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            DEFAULT_CORNER_LENGTH_DP,
            displayMetrics);

    // Sets guidelines to default until specified otherwise
    mGuidelines = CropImageView.DEFAULT_GUIDELINES;
}

/**
 * Set the initial crop window size and position. This is dependent on the
 * size and position of the image being cropped.
 *
 * @param bitmapRect the bounding box around the image being cropped
 */
private void initCropWindow(Rect bitmapRect) {

    if (bitmapRect.width() == 0 || bitmapRect.height() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Tells the attribute functions the crop window has already been
    // initialized
    if (!initializedCropWindow) {
        initializedCropWindow = true;
    }

    if (mFixAspectRatio
            && (bitmapRect.left != 0 || bitmapRect.right != 0
            || bitmapRect.top != 0 || bitmapRect.bottom != 0)) {

        // If the image aspect ratio is wider than the crop aspect ratio,
        // then the image height is the determining initial length. Else,
        // vice-versa.
        if (AspectRatioUtil.calculateAspectRatio(bitmapRect) > mTargetAspectRatio) {

            Edge.TOP.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.top);
            Edge.BOTTOM.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.bottom);

            final float centerX = getWidth() / 2f;

            //dirty fix for wrong crop overlay aspect ratio when using fixed aspect ratio
            mTargetAspectRatio = (float) mAspectRatioX / mAspectRatioY;

            // Limits the aspect ratio to no less than 40 wide or 40 tall
            final float cropWidth = Math.max(Edge.MIN_CROP_LENGTH_PX,
                    AspectRatioUtil.calculateWidth(Edge.TOP.getCoordinate(),
                            Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate(),
                            mTargetAspectRatio));

            // Create new TargetAspectRatio if the original one does not fit
            // the screen
            if (cropWidth == Edge.MIN_CROP_LENGTH_PX) {
                mTargetAspectRatio = (Edge.MIN_CROP_LENGTH_PX) / (Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate() - Edge.TOP.getCoordinate());
            }

            final float halfCropWidth = cropWidth / 2f;
            Edge.LEFT.setCoordinate(centerX - halfCropWidth);
            Edge.RIGHT.setCoordinate(centerX + halfCropWidth);

        } else {

            Edge.LEFT.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.left);
            Edge.RIGHT.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.right);

            final float centerY = getHeight() / 2f;

            // Limits the aspect ratio to no less than 40 wide or 40 tall
            final float cropHeight = Math.max(Edge.MIN_CROP_LENGTH_PX,
                    AspectRatioUtil.calculateHeight(Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate(),
                            Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate(),
                            mTargetAspectRatio));

            // Create new TargetAspectRatio if the original one does not fit
            // the screen
            if (cropHeight == Edge.MIN_CROP_LENGTH_PX) {
                mTargetAspectRatio = (Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate() - Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate()) / Edge.MIN_CROP_LENGTH_PX;
            }

            final float halfCropHeight = cropHeight / 2f;
            Edge.TOP.setCoordinate(centerY - halfCropHeight);
            Edge.BOTTOM.setCoordinate(centerY + halfCropHeight);
        }

    } else { // ... do not fix aspect ratio...

        // Initialize crop window to have 10% padding w/ respect to image.
        final float horizontalPadding = 0.1f * bitmapRect.width();
        final float verticalPadding = 0.1f * bitmapRect.height();

        Edge.LEFT.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.left + horizontalPadding);
        Edge.TOP.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.top + verticalPadding);
        Edge.RIGHT.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.right - horizontalPadding);
        Edge.BOTTOM.setCoordinate(bitmapRect.bottom - verticalPadding);
    }
}

/**
 * Indicates whether the crop window is small enough that the guidelines
 * should be shown. Public because this function is also used to determine
 * if the center handle should be focused.
 *
 * @return boolean Whether the guidelines should be shown or not
 */
public static boolean showGuidelines() {
    if ((Math.abs(Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate() - Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate()) < DEFAULT_SHOW_GUIDELINES_LIMIT)
            || (Math.abs(Edge.TOP.getCoordinate() - Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate()) < DEFAULT_SHOW_GUIDELINES_LIMIT)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private void drawRuleOfThirdsGuidelines(Canvas canvas) {

    float w = mBorderPaint.getStrokeWidth();
    float l = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate() + w;
    float t = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate() + w;
    float r = Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate() - w;
    float b = Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate() - w;

    if (mCropShape == CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL) {
        l += 15 * mGuidelinePaint.getStrokeWidth();
        t += 15 * mGuidelinePaint.getStrokeWidth();
        r -= 15 * mGuidelinePaint.getStrokeWidth();
        b -= 15 * mGuidelinePaint.getStrokeWidth();
    }

    // Draw vertical guidelines.
    final float oneThirdCropWidth = Edge.getWidth() / 3;

    final float x1 = l + oneThirdCropWidth;
    canvas.drawLine(x1, t, x1, b, mGuidelinePaint);
    final float x2 = r - oneThirdCropWidth;
    canvas.drawLine(x2, t, x2, b, mGuidelinePaint);

    // Draw horizontal guidelines.
    final float oneThirdCropHeight = Edge.getHeight() / 3;

    final float y1 = t + oneThirdCropHeight;
    canvas.drawLine(l, y1, r, y1, mGuidelinePaint);
    final float y2 = b - oneThirdCropHeight;
    canvas.drawLine(l, y2, r, y2, mGuidelinePaint);
}

private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas, Rect bitmapRect) {

    final float l = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate();
    final float t = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate();
    final float r = Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate();
    final float b = Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate();

    if (mCropShape == CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE) {
        canvas.drawRect(bitmapRect.left, bitmapRect.top, bitmapRect.right, t, mBackgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(bitmapRect.left, b, bitmapRect.right, bitmapRect.bottom, mBackgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(bitmapRect.left, t, l, b, mBackgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(r, t, bitmapRect.right, b, mBackgroundPaint);
    } else {
        Path circleSelectionPath = new Path();
        mRectF.set(l, t, r, b);
        circleSelectionPath.addOval(mRectF, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(circleSelectionPath, Region.Op.XOR);
        canvas.drawRect(bitmapRect.left, bitmapRect.top, bitmapRect.right, bitmapRect.bottom, mBackgroundPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

private void drawCorners(Canvas canvas) {

    float w = mBorderPaint.getStrokeWidth();
    final float l = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate() + w;
    final float t = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate() + w;
    final float r = Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate() - w;
    final float b = Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate() - w;

    // Top left
    canvas.drawLine(l - mCornerOffset, t - mCornerExtension, l - mCornerOffset, t + mCornerLength, mCornerPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(l, t - mCornerOffset, l + mCornerLength, t - mCornerOffset, mCornerPaint);

    // Top right
    canvas.drawLine(r + mCornerOffset, t - mCornerExtension, r + mCornerOffset, t + mCornerLength, mCornerPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(r, t - mCornerOffset, r - mCornerLength, t - mCornerOffset, mCornerPaint);

    // Bottom left
    canvas.drawLine(l - mCornerOffset, b + mCornerExtension, l - mCornerOffset, b - mCornerLength, mCornerPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(l, b + mCornerOffset, l + mCornerLength, b + mCornerOffset, mCornerPaint);

    // Bottom left
    canvas.drawLine(r + mCornerOffset, b + mCornerExtension, r + mCornerOffset, b - mCornerLength, mCornerPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(r, b + mCornerOffset, r - mCornerLength, b + mCornerOffset, mCornerPaint);
}

/**
 * Handles a {@link android.view.MotionEvent#ACTION_DOWN} event.
 *
 * @param x the x-coordinate of the down action
 * @param y the y-coordinate of the down action
 */
private void onActionDown(float x, float y) {

    final float left = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate();
    final float top = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate();
    final float right = Edge.RIGHT.getCoordinate();
    final float bottom = Edge.BOTTOM.getCoordinate();

    mPressedHandle = HandleUtil.getPressedHandle(x, y, left, top, right, bottom, mHandleRadius);

    if (mPressedHandle == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate the offset of the touch point from the precise location
    // of the handle. Save these values in a member variable since we want
    // to maintain this offset as we drag the handle.
    mTouchOffset = HandleUtil.getOffset(mPressedHandle, x, y, left, top, right, bottom);

    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Handles a {@link android.view.MotionEvent#ACTION_UP} or
 * {@link android.view.MotionEvent#ACTION_CANCEL} event.
 */
private void onActionUp() {

    if (mPressedHandle == null) {
        return;
    }

    mPressedHandle = null;

    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Handles a {@link android.view.MotionEvent#ACTION_MOVE} event.
 *
 * @param x the x-coordinate of the move event
 * @param y the y-coordinate of the move event
 */
private void onActionMove(float x, float y) {

    if (mPressedHandle == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Adjust the coordinates for the finger position's offset (i.e. the
    // distance from the initial touch to the precise handle location).
    // We want to maintain the initial touch's distance to the pressed
    // handle so that the crop window size does not "jump".
    x += mTouchOffset.first;
    y += mTouchOffset.second;

    // Calculate the new crop window size/position.
    if (mFixAspectRatio) {
        mPressedHandle.updateCropWindow(x, y, mTargetAspectRatio, mBitmapRect, mSnapRadius);
    } else {
        mPressedHandle.updateCropWindow(x, y, mBitmapRect, mSnapRadius);
    }
    invalidate();
}
//endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try using Picasso. It does all the scaling for you in the background after you put it into your Gradle build. [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: thank you I just hope its got an overlay window I can drag to scale because that is my motive

Comment: I know you can dynamically scale it to the size you want inside its method to and pixels. Just hope it all works out for you.